# How to Train several Models with Spark K-means

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need to train several models with Spark K-means, now I can do something like  the following

```java
for(JavaRDD<Vector> parsedData : data){
   KMeansModel clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData.rdd(), numClusters, numIterations);
}
```

But this is too slow,
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Spark k-means is *very* slow. Use ELKI instead. It's 100x faster in my experience - so unless you have 100 nodes, use it.